# Behavior of executor service in cluster

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor, scheduledexecutorservice

I had written a code using executor service in java. Here I am creating 10  worker threads to process database fetched rows. Each thread will be assigned with one resultant row. This approach will work fine when the application is deployed and running on single instance/node.

Can anyone suggest how this will behave when my application is deployed in multiple nodes/cluster?
Do I have to take care of any part of code before deploying into cluster?

04/12/15: Any more suggestions?

Comment: Any more suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider the overhead of each task. Unless the task is of moderate size, you might want to batch them.

In a distributed context the overhead if much higher so you are more likely to need to batch the work.

You will need to a framework, so the considerations will depend on the framework you chose.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for your time. I have some confusion in understanding your reply. Could you please elaborate what kind of batch work you are referring here? Is it spring batch?

Comment: @user4325796 I mean you pass more than one row per task. You only need about two tasks for every CPU you have.  Any more than this may increase overhead.

Comment: Hi Peter, yes, as suggested I will reduce no of worker threads to 2 and will assign all work to them.

Comment: @user4325796 how many CPUs do you have? Multiply that by 2 and this is the number of threads to use. e.g. If you have 8 CPUs, use 16 threads.

Comment: Hi peter, right now I am not sure about no of cpu which we will going to use. I will keep this in mind before complete implementation. It will be helpful if you can explain why only 2 threads per cpu? Please provide the link if any article is present on the same. Thank you.

Comment: This is from experience. Most CPU bound thread pools you only want at most one thread per CPU. However with an un even load, 2x might be optimal. You won't know until you try it, but don't assume more threads is better.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions Peter:)

Comment: @user4325796 This might be the best link really ;) i.e. you can take my word for it, that its a good place to start, but also your mileage will vary so test it. http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2015/10/my-bio.html